# Does Visual Studio have profiles similar to VScode's profiles

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022, development-environment, visual-studio-extensions

Are there any Visual Studio (2022) profiles/environments similar to Visual Studio Code? For example, if I wanted to use some extensions separately from others. I program in C++ and C# in Visual Studio, or are there any other extensions required to make environments/profiles possible?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: you would make an project and define which nuget packes the project should use , and make other settings for the project if you that mean

Comment: If your gonna flag it for deletion or close the question. Please send a proper question where this is solved. thnx

Comment: I dont rly use nuget in all my projects. I do Unity development with some extensions

Comment: that doesn't really matter and not all dll are nuget packages, you can have multiple project for every project map, each can be have other properties

Comment: What do you mean, i dont understand that grammar at all, and what im trying to specifically use this for is extensions

Comment: you start a new prohect, there you can select a project type lets say uniti3d in c#. in taht project you add dll as linik or install nuget packages, depending on your needs. next you add another project to the same porjct map that you use to define a service and then you can add another for lets say a dll and so on, you can defien the order rof compilation, but all belongs to one project map

Comment: But i need this for extensions, not packages or dlls. Visual Studio Extensions. Like Visual assist and Resharper

Comment: reshrper has an extension, https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/resharper/buy/#discounts but depending on your use it costs and vsial assist https://www.wholetomato.com/downloads also

Comment: im just giving examples, but i need profiles like visual studio code, none of your comments have helped

Comment: you only didn_#t undestand my comment about starting a project, where you can specify a programming language that visual studio support, that is the same as in vs code, when you install tthe IDe you can select what kind of programm you want ti develpe and different lets say profles are isnatllaed, for every new project you wnat tio add to the projecz map, you can define which langue you want top support, there are already a lot of profles, but not as many as vs code has

Comment: I dont think you know what vscode profiles are.They are like mini dev environments, with their own configurations. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles

Comment: @RedArchfiend955 VS has .vssettings files that can control IDE that could be similar to profiles but I think it does not affect extensions. Only some layout & settings.

Comment: Hmm @PawełŁukasik, thats helpful ig but not what im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Visual Studio have profiles similar to VScode's profiles

**The answer is NO.** The strictly same feature does not exist in Visual Studio for this.

Please note that the composition of these two tools is completely different (I am not just referring to the profile function, most of the functions are different). Only in a few special cases do these two tools overlap, such as React App:

[ASP.NET Core app with React in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022)

In this situation, Visual Studio also needs to rely on the configuration of VSCode, such as launch.json (in fact, in this case, VS itself will also generate this configuration, which is how it is designed).

But for the vast majority of cases, these two tools have no intersection.

Generally, Visual Studio does not have built-in support for user profiles or environments like Visual Studio Code does. All extensions, settings, and configurations are applied globally across all instances of Visual Studio.

There is an exception, but this exception has little practical significance, this is when you do VS extension development, if you run an extension (even if you did not write anything actual), a clean new one will be generated at this time VS instance. But you can't usually use this instance to work. Although this kind of thing exists, it has no practical significance in working.

[Start developing extensions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022)

Again, VS does not have this kind of functionality that you have in VSCode. The two tools are completely different. You need to follow [the official documentation of VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/?view=vs-2022) to understand how to use VS. In addition, for VS, there is no extension that can implement such a thing as profile.

There is a workaround, but this workaround is not perfect. It can only solve part of the problem, and it is not the same as what you want:

You can control the configuration of C# or C++ by [importing and exporting settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022#import-and-export-settings).

However, I suggest that you don't think about such things, because it is very troublesome to implement the same thing in VS now, and it cannot fully cover what you need.

What you want makes sense, if you need functionality in this area, you can submit a feature request to the developer community:

[Visual Studio - Request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest)

Comment: Thanks! this was rly useful, and Ive already requested a feature. if you can do me a favor, plz upvote this post so it gets higher in google's search results, becuase i could not find anything related to profiles in Visual Studio.